# how does a non existing sid/pgid process possible?

Tags: process, proc

I've listed processes on Ubuntu 17.04, Noticed the following process:

```
root@user-virtual-machine:~# ps  xao pid=,ppid=,pgid=,sid=
1603      1   1601   1601
```

however process 1601 does not exist.

```
root@user-virtual-machine:~# ls /proc/1601
ls: cannot access '/proc/1601': No such file or directory
```

and as you can see /proc/1603/status still references 1601.

```
root@user-virtual-machine:~# cat /proc/1603/status
Name:   VGAuthService
Umask:  0000
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   1603
Ngid:   0
Pid:    1603
PPid:   1
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    0   0   0   0
Gid:    0   0   0   0
FDSize: 64
Groups:  
NStgid: 1603
NSpid:  1603
NSpgid: 1601
NSsid:  1601
```

important to mention, i'm on the host (not inside a container).

How is it even possible? how setsid/setpgid was set for a non existing process?

Comment: Related: [What is the reason for performing a doubłe fork when creating a daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, interesting link, but didn't find an answer there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's a session without leader which is quite common for daemons.

Sessions are used primarily to implement login sessions on terminals.

When you start a daemon from a terminal, you want it to disconnect from the terminal. For the process of that daemon to no longer have the terminal as its controlling terminal, you need to start a new session. So, typically the daemon will fork a process (which ensures the child is not a process group leader, and so that the parent can exit), and call `setsid()` in that child.

That child will be the leader of a new session, so not the session controlled by the terminal. However, if that process ever opened another terminal device without passing the O_NOCTTY flag, it would cause that terminal to be the controlling terminal of that session which is not something you want for a daemon. To make sure it doesn't happen, it's a good idea to fork once more, then the child is no longer a session leader and opening a terminal device will be harmless there.

The parent has no reason to hang around and exits, so that session no longer has a leader.

So it's quite common for daemons to run in sessions without leaders.

Here, looking for processes in sessions without leaders, I see a lot of daemons:

```
$ ps -je | grep -wf <(comm -23 <(ps -eo sid= | sort -u) <(ps -eo pid= | sort -u) | awk '$1{print $1}')
 1722  1714  1714 ?        00:00:01 atopacctd
 2540  2178  2178 ?        00:00:00 ddclient - slee
 2985  2984  2984 ?        00:00:00 dnsmasq
 2987  2984  2984 ?        00:00:00 dnsmasq
 8428  8427  8427 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-d
 8726  8725  8725 ?        00:01:17 pulseaudio
11456 11455 11455 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-d
11649 11648 11648 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio
```